# For Interaction terms of 2 variables (that each have different levels), can you do Interaction of each level of the variable

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am working on a logistic regression model in 'R'. The model includes a variable called 'CB_0718' with four levels (when CB_0718=1, CB_0718=2, CB_0718=3, and CB_0718=4). The first level is the reference variable. There is also a variable called 'survyear2018' that has two levels; when it equals 1, it is the reference variable, and when it equals 2, it is the second level. There is also a variable 'pov138two' with two levels.

After running my regression, I obtained interaction terms (including the p-value from results) as follows:

```r
CB_07182:survyear2018, p-value = 0.400468    
CB_07182:pov138two2, p-value = 0.061122  
CB_07183:pov138two2, p-value = 0.230693   
CB_07184:pov138two2, p-value = 0.922266  
survyear2018:pov138two2, p-value = 0.764519  
CB_07182:survyear2018:pov138two2, p-value = 0.290771
```

Can anyone tell me why I got an interaction term with three different levels of 'CB_0718' (excluding the reference variable) and 'pov138two'? Whereas, the other interaction terms, which seem good, only show:

```r
CB_07182:survyear2018
survyear2018:pov138two2
CB_07182:survyear2018:pov138two2
```

Why did 'R' show the three levels of 'CB_0718' (excluding the reference level) when interacting with 'pov138two'? Is it because it wanted to show the "direction" of the interaction of 'CB_07182'*'pov138two' is significant at the alpha = 0.10 level, since the p-value is 0.061, so it needed to break it up by levels of 'CB_0718' to show that? Whereas, for the other sets of interaction terms, none of them were significant, so there was no need to break up the levels of 'CB_0718'? Any ideas? I have no idea.

You can find an image of the other variables included in the model at this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CC0d.png).

Comment: Welcome to SO, but your question is better suited to StackExchange, since it isn't a specific programming problem.  In brief, your model is overparameterised.  I suspect you have an overal mean term in your model.  This means that, for every main effect and interaction in your model, at least one level is aliased and its coefficient cannot be estimated.  Model parameters reflect differences from this unestimable, reference level.  Also, the "overall mean" does not estimate the mean of your data, but rather the mean of observations whose independent variables take these reference levels.

Comment: @Limey I think OP misunderstood what you meant by "better suited to Stack Exchange", as [they've reposted this on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390407/461068).

Comment: @F1Krazy Then what did they mean by that? Sorry not familiar with this site and the differences w the other one , and why you can cross-post

Comment: Honestly, I don't know what they meant. Stack Exchange has [a large number of sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites), but I don't know which one they thought this would be better suited to or why they thought that. (IMO, this question is perfectly fine here on Stack Overflow.) Generally, you shouldn't cross-post questions, and you shouldn't post programming questions on Meta Stack Exchange, as it's for questions about the Stack Exchange network itself.